# Values on a simple 'number line' chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have 5 dynamic values:

| MIN | MID | MAX | Actual | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 150 | 200 | 119 | 144 |

I need a simple visualization (chart I guess) that is a 'number line' from `MIN` till `MAX` with markers on `MID`, `Actual` and `Target` and which of course updates automatically upon any value change.

Something like this:

```
MIN     Actual   Target    MID                          MAX
*---------*---------*-------*-----------------------------*
100      119       144     150                          200
```

Comment: Normally, the TEXT is under the line and the Number is above the line.. 0 . 0 It this OK?

Comment: @Lee Sure, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

As of Excel 2019, there's no "direct" way of doing this. So we need to use a workaround using a scatter chart. However, this method still requires fair amount of manual work (Or that I'm unaware of ways to do it automatically)

So first proceed to insert a Scatter chart (Scatter with straight lines and markers OR Scatter with smooth lines and markers)

Then, right click the chart, Click `Select data` You'll land here:
[image]

Click add. In the new popup window, Select `Series name` and click on `MIN`, `Series X value` and click on the value, and change `Select Y value` to 0. Like so:
[image]

Add a series for each value till you have this:
[image]

Change the chart area so that it looks more like a number line:
[image]

Now right-click on the X-axis (Also known by excel as "Horizontal (Value) Axis") and click on format axis. Change the values to your liking, But I prefer these changes.

- **Bounds/Minimum** = 90
- **Bounds/Maximum** = 210
- **Units/Major** = 10

Next step would be to add labels. Click on the data point, like so: [image] and Click `Add data labels > Add data labels`. A new data label will be added. Click on the the data label, and click on `Format Data Label`. Check `Series name` and `X Value` (if you want to). Now Select `Above` as `Label position` (or `below` if you like it to be so). Do the same for every point. Final result would look like this: 
[image]

Comment: Thank you. What I need is for the horizontal axis values to start with the value of MIN and finish with the value of MAX automatically.

Comment: @fishmong3r Can you elaborate that a bit more please? Like do you want to hide the extra values that are currently appearing on the chart?

Comment: So, on your last screenshot the starting value is 90. I want it to be the value of MIN, which is 100 at the moment. If I change the value of MIN to 105 in my table then it should be the starting value. Same applies for MAX. In your example it goes till 210, but it has to go till the value of MAX whatever that is.

Comment: @fishmong3r Unfortunately — I don't think that could be possible with this method :(

Comment: Don't use a hyphen as a separator, it looks like a minus sign in front of a number.

Comment: @JonPeltier Figured out that line was practically useless, so I edited out the entire line :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever say there's no way to do something in Excel.

Here's my data:

[image: Data for Number Line]

A1:B5 contains the data you provided.

A4:E4 will be used as labels. A4 has this formula, which is filled across to E4:

```
=A1&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&A2
```

A6:E6 contain the X values for the chart. A6 has this formula, which is filled across to E6:

```
=(A2-$A2)/($C2-$A2)
```

Note that A6 (min) shows zero, and C6 (max) shows one. These will be the endpoints of the X axis.

A7:E7 contain the Y values for the chart, which are just zeros.

Here are my charts:

[image: Step by Step Number Line]

The first chart is an XY Scatter chart made using A6:E7.

The second chart has adjusted axis limits, with X hard-coded to min=0 and max=1, and Y hard-coded to min=-1 and max=1.

The third chart has been shrunk in height, and within it the plot area has been shrunk further.

The gridlines in the fourth chart have been deleted. The axis tick labels have been changed to position: None. The vertical axis line format has been changed to No Line.

Finally, data labels have been added to the fifth chart. The position is center, and values have been taken from cells, that is, from A4:E4.